# Drawing a circle with cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to draw a circle in my scene with :

```
- (void) draw
{
     ccDrawColor4F(100, 100, 100, 255);
    CGPoint center = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
    CGFloat radius = 10.f;
    CGFloat angle = 0.f;
    NSInteger segments = 10;
    BOOL drawLineToCenter = YES;

    ccDrawCircle(center, radius, angle, segments, drawLineToCenter);
}
```

Well, I get some white,small circle, not filled, with some line from the center to the circle (like a clock).

So, first why are the colors are not as requested, how can I fill it with my own color? whats the line in the middle?

And, what if i want to change the color after a second? whats the best way to do that? Set a timer with a global variable?

Answer (score 2):

```
#import <OpenGLES/ES1/gl.h>

- (void) draw
{
    glLineWidth(5*CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR()); //set the thickness to 5 pixels for example
    ccDrawColor4F(0.4,0.4,0.4, 1);
    ccDrawLine([self anchorPoint], _peg.position);
    CGPoint center = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
    CGFloat radius = 10.0;
    CGFloat angle = 360;
    NSInteger segments = 360;
    BOOL drawLineToCenter = NO;

    ccDrawCircle(center, radius, angle, segments, drawLineToCenter);
}
```

If you want to update the circle's color every second, schedule the update method and implement it as follows :

```
-(void) update:(float)dt
{
    if(startTime == 0){
        startTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    }
    double elapsedTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - startTime;
    if(elapsedTime > 1){
        //update ccDrawColor4F here, for example just changing the Red component:
        ccDrawColor4F((float)arc4random() / UINT_MAX,0.4,0.4, 1);
        startTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    }
}
```

This should fix your issue. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The colour values are floats not bytes, so you need to pass in something more like

ccDrawColor4F(0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1.f);

You may also want to reset the colour back to white after you've called your draw methods just for the sake of consistency.

To get a filled circle, use this function instead

```
void ccDrawSolidCircle( CGPoint center, float r, float a, NSUInteger segs, ccColor4F color);
```

The circle is always drawn from the middle, so presumably if you choose 4 segments, you'll get 4 lines drawn from the middle. Although I'm not too sure on that, I don't use primitives very much at all. As for the colour change, yes I would opt for some form of timer to change the values passed into the ccDrawColor4F method. But bear in mind that you want as little non-drawing code in the draw method as possible, so perhaps work out the colour change in another update related function.